# Java library to manipulate and overlap images

Tags: java, image-manipulation

I am looking for a Java imaging library to manipulate and overlap images.

More specifically, I would like to have a base image, an outline of sorts, and be able to change the size and color filling. Then, I'd like to take some of the resulting images and overlap them to create a new one.

I was thinking I should use SVG, so that I can be able to manipulate the images, and I suppose overlapping shouldn't be too hard. However, I haven't done this before, so I am basically looking for confirmation that SVG is the right way to go, or for suggestions of alternatives.

EDIT: I think I should also say I want to display this on a website. Should I also look into Javascript image manipulation? I am thinking Java might be better suited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you look more into SVG as it sounds like it might be the best approach. SVG can use XML do define your image(s), which can then be rendered or converted to other formats. The nice thing about SVG is that its not dependent on a specific platform. Browsers are starting to support SVG natively, and there are plenty of tools for working with SVG.

Batik and FOP are two good Java libraries that work with SVG.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The point is, do I need any extra functionality that an SVG library will offer, over the Java 2D library already suggested by the other answer?

Comment: I think it depends on how much coding you want to do and how complex your needs are. SVG should do everything you need (and more), but you will need to learn SVG. Java 2D API can also do it all, but you will have to code it all.

Answer (score 1):

The Java 2D API can easily do the job.